# nginx http server location include unknown directive error

Tags: nginx, configuration, config

my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream app_servers {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
    }

    server {
        listen 6200;
        server_name test;
        add_header X-GG-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        include rewrite.conf;
    }
}
```

and my rewrite.conf in the same folder as that

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^/some-custom-destination/?$ /destination/detail?id=33;
    proxy_pass http: //app_servers;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 400 404 /;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /error.html;
    location = /error.html {
        root /etc/nginx/;
    }
}
```

when I use nginx -s reload command getting that error : nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "location" in /etc/nginx/rewrite.conf:1

How can I fix that?

Help, please. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how you are getting that specific error. When I test your configuration, the `proxy_pass` fails because of a spurious space, and the second `location` fails because it's nested within an exact match `location` block.

Comment: spaces are don't matter because of copy paste. I just would like to split my config as location as like that. How can I split my config?

Comment: please, nginx -t before you reload (or try to)...

Comment: You cannot nest inside a = location block. It’s even true mathematically as 1=1 checks out but 1=3 doesn’t quite register. Take your « exact match » requests separated and make your = / just / if it doesnt need to absolutely be domain.com - location / will also match anything under domain.com/blah/ if not specified elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the space in your proxy_pass directive, there is one more issue with your location block.

From the nginx documentation about nginx location directive (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), you cannot have a nested location inside a location block “location = /”.

```
“Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates. For example, if a “/” request happens frequently, defining “location = /” will speed up the processing of these requests, as search terminates right after the first comparison. Such a location cannot obviously contain nested locations.”
```